# Passport auth callback instead of redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

```
passport.authenticate('local-register',{
            successRedirect: '/login',
            failureRedirect: '/path_to_greatness',
        })(req, res, next);
```

I'm writing an API which is stateless so above method like successRedirect won't suite my needs. But I still want to use passport layer, how do I have a callback?

Comment: It's pretty open-ended. Could you try something and ask if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback to `passport.authenticate`, which should suit a wide range of use cases. When passing a callback, you must create the session yourself (assuming authentication is successful). ([docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate))

Here's a simple example of use:

```
function handler(req, res, next) {
  // assuming we're using a "local" strategy
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, params) => {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (!user) return next(new Error('Authentication Failed'))

    // user is authenticated, create a session
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) return next(err)
      // handle response
      res.status(200).json({ some: 'data' })
    })
  })(req, res, next)
}
```

Comment: He don't need any session since he mentioned he's using JWT.

Comment: @Jennifer the OP makes no reference to JWT. Yes, a pure stateless API would use an authentication system similar to JWT, but the OP explicitly asked for a callback solution for passportjs, which relies on sessions.

Comment: If I want to use JWT, will this suite my needs? how to disable session in passport?

Comment: You can use passport without sessions (that is also explained in the docs). There is a npm module `passport-jwt` for integrating JWT with passport, and if you don't want the session, don't create it (i.e. no `req.logIn`). You can do whatever application specific stuff on top of that.